# How to create a environment-application on aws beanstalk for a python2.7.14 program using aws eb console?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am completely new to AWS, and MacOS too. However, I am trying to create simple python apps in aws beanstalk. I got their default demo app- (the one that comes as an option while creating an environment/application) working. I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html#python-flask-create-app), and the code works locally (python 2.7.14).

But when I upload this application.py and requirements.txt via a zip, the compiled application shows health 'ok' but 'internal server error' when I load the application url.

I dont know how to debug or even what to debug as the code is quite straightforward: it is mostly an incompatible environment issue.

So, I'm looking everywhere how to make my AWSEB environment a python2.7 instead of python3.4 that its giving me, for both preconfigured docker python and preconfigured python platforms.

I am confused. How do I make my AWSEB environment / application a python 2.7.14, the one I use locally and is working well?

For reference, here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask

# print a nice greeting.
def say_hello(username = "World"):
    return '<p>Hello %s!</p>\n' % username

# some bits of text for the page.
header_text = '''
    <html>\n<head> <title>EB Flask Test</title> </head>\n<body>'''
instructions = '''
    <p><em>Hint</em>: This is a RESTful web service! Append a username
    to the URL (for example: <code>/Thelonious</code>) to say hello to
    someone specific.</p>\n'''
home_link = '<p><a href="/">Back</a></p>\n'
footer_text = '</body>\n</html>'

# EB looks for an 'application' callable by default.
application = Flask(__name__)

# add a rule for the index page.
application.add_url_rule('/', 'index', (lambda: header_text +
    say_hello() + instructions + footer_text))

# add a rule when the page is accessed with a name appended to the site
# URL.
application.add_url_rule('/<username>', 'hello', (lambda username:
    header_text + say_hello(username) + home_link + footer_text))

# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Setting debug to True enables debug output. This line should be
    # removed before deploying a production app.
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

requirements.txt

```
click==6.7
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

I'm running into path issues while installing the AWSEB cli- so please restrict your answers to using the console. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a different version of the platform for your application, you need to specify using a mechanism elastic beanstalk provides, ie through config.yml file. You need to create a config.yml file with environment/platform requirements and place the file under .elasticbeanstalk folder at base folder of your application.

You can see the config.yml setup and format [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-before.html)

And there are many [supported platforms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.python).

> how do I make my aws eb environment/application a python2.7.14

Based on the above document you need to specify the following in config.yml file:

> global:   default_platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.7.1 running
>   Python 2.7

Different config files help to customize the EB config/environment. More [here](http://You%20can%20read%20about%20different%20config%20files%20and%20why%20they%20are%20used:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-before.html#configuration-options-before-ebextensions)

Comment: is that one line the full content of the config file? Also, you said .yml file at the beginning but then specify .xml- do both work or should I still go with .yml? and are you sure about naming the folder as .elasticbeanstalk? (because the docs mention a .ebextensions folder)

Comment: It should be a config.yml file. Thanks for pointing, updated. 
The file name and foldername are correct. The purpose of .ebextentions is different. You can read about different config files and why they are used: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-methods-before.html#configuration-options-before-ebextensions

You can auto generate the file using "eb init" command too. 

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok, i included both .ebextensions and .elasticbeanstalk folders at the same level as my application.py. This didnt work. I changed both .xml to .yml-this didnt work either

Comment: I presume there is issue with the config files. To ensure the proper struture, you delete the .elasticbeanstalk folders and use "eb init" to auto generate the files.
Use eb init:
Read the document first:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html

eg:
eb platform list -- to see the supported platforms list 

So for python: 
you can pass the required value thru eb init -p xxx